# GWT не отображаются данные из модели

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, rpc

```
ApplicationServiceAsync serviceAsync = GWT.create(ApplicationService.class);
SimpleEventBus eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();
NavigationController navigationController = new NavigationController(this);

DepartmentModel departmentModel = new DepartmentModel();

new MainPageController(serviceAsync, departmentModel);

MainPageView mainPageView = new MainPageView(departmentModel);

mainPagePresenter = new MainPagePresenter(serviceAsync, eventBus, mainPageView);

mainPagePresenter.go(RootPanel.get());
```

Это пример метода `onModuleLoad()`, controller сеттит List в model полученный через RPC. Во View Label отображающий `size()` листа. Ну так вот он равен 0. Хотя данные выбираются.

Более того есть странная штука.

```
VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
initWidget(vPanel); //Window.alert(String.valueOf(departmentModel.getDepartments().size()));
final Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(departmentModel.getDepartments().size()));
vPanel.add(label);
```

Если раскомментить Window.alert, то отображается в alert 0, а в Lable количество строк. Такой вот странный баг. Ну это в Mozilla так.